# Is bullet drop present in far cry 4?

Tags: far-cry-4

Is there bullet drop in far cry 4 ? I know arrows do drop but I can't find any information about bullet drop.
Also do bullets penetrate certain surfaces or they don't penetrate at all ?

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find any really compelling evidence but the [consensus](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/795264-far-cry-4/71593128) seems to be no [bullet drop](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/632847-far-cry-3/answers/342895-is-there-bullet-drop) (except for the bow). A comment on this [website](http://www.gamespot.com/articles/even-more-evidence-for-far-cry-4-comes-to-light/1100-6417391/) also suggests it's not present.

There seems to be even less information on bullet penetration of the environment. However, I know you could shoot through the environment in far cry 2 and through people in far cry 3 so it seems likely there is some functionality for bullet penetration.

Answer (score 3):

**Bullet Drop:**
I asked a friend of mine who plays Far Cry 4 a LOT and he said that in his experience only the arrows seem to drop. Bullets do not have bullet drop in his experience.

**Bullet Penetration:**
Far Cry does have bullet penetration in some weapons. I haven't found an exhautive list yet but so far I know that the *Zastava M93 Black Arrow* and the *Gepard GM6 Lynx* have penetrating rounds which ignore cover. You can see in the descriptions in the screenshots that it mentions that they can penetrate walls.

**Zastava M93 Black Arrow .50 BMG**
[image: Zastava M93 Black Arrow .50 BMG]

**Gepard GM6 Lynx .50 BMG**
[image: Gepard GM6 Lynx .50 BMG]